# How to detect more or fewer columns in a CSV, in a Flat File Source SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis

I have a problem with a CSV file with open source flat file in an SSIS package.

I set up 10 columns in the file, but I try to detect those lines that have 9 or fewer columns or more than 10 on my own.

If I declare Omit the error, omit the entire line. If I declare Redirect line, not continuous by the red arrow. If I declare Component error, fail to detect a line that contains 10 columns.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can add more columns in the Columns page. You can specify the widht/delimiter for each individual column.  Does the file use delimiters or is it a fixed-width file?

Comment: The file use delimiters like this:
1243123;1241241;124124;124214;
1243123;1241241;124124;124214;

But if a line is like:
1243123;1241241;124124;

I can't verifiy the columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to handle this with a Script task.

You can either use the Script to pre-handle the rows that don't have 10 columns, and then send only a .csv file with 10 columns in every row to the DataFlow, or you can just do then entire import in the script task, handling every row according to its contents one at a time.

Comment: also it serves a script component, Data Flow task, but you'll have to get all a line in a column